# CXF DynamicWebservice client dateTIme converted to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: cxf, webservice-client, jaxb2

One of my webservice argument is of type java.util.Date and when I am generating the CXF dynamic webservice client, due to the default behavior of JAXB its getting translated to XMLGregorianCalendar. However, as the webservice hosted on the server expects a Date object, when the actual webservice is called ClassCastException is thrown.

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar
>     at *.*.CloseSet_WrapperTypeHelper1.createWrapperObject(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:103)
>     ... 36 more
> ```

Code to create the CXF Dynamic webservice client is as follows:

```
private static JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory
            .newInstance();

...

private CachedClient getClient(String wsdlUrl) {
...
dcf.createClient(wsdlUrl, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"C:\\datebinding.xjb"}))
...
}
```

With the same binding file if I create the classes using the wsdl2java tool, the class created is showing the field as java.util.Date type

```
C:\>"c:\apache-cxf-2.2.12\apache-cxf-2.2.12\bin\wsdl2java" -b datebinding.xjb http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/MyService?wsdl

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "closeSet", propOrder = {
    "instanceId",
    "activationDate"
})
public class CloseSet {

    protected long instanceId;
    @XmlElement(type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected Date activationDate;
```

If binding file is removed

```
C:\>"c:\apache-cxf-2.2.12\apache-cxf-2.2.12\bin\wsdl2java" http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/MyService?wsdl

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "closeSet", propOrder = {
    "instanceId",
    "activationDate"
})
public class CloseSet {

    protected long instanceId;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar activationDate;
```

So I am suspecting somehow my custom binding file is not getting picked up by the CXF dynamic client.

CXF/JAXB dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Webservice hosted on server

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.*.*.configuration.IConfigWebService")
public class ConfigWebService

public void closeSet(long id, Date date)
            throws ObjectNotFoundException, DuplicateObjectException {
```

wsdl snippet - http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/MyService?wsdl

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://ws.*.*.*.com" xmlns:ns2="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://impl.config.*.*.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ConfigWebServiceService" targetNamespace="http://impl.config.*.*.com/">
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/MyService?wsdl=IConfigWebService.wsdl" namespace="http://ws.*.*.*.com"></wsdl:import>
<wsdl:binding name="ConfigWebServiceServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:IConfigWebService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

<wsdl:operation name="closeSet">
    <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input name="closeSet">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="closeSetResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
```

http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/ConfigService?wsdl=IConfigWebService.wsdl

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://ws.*.*.*.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="IConfigWebService" targetNamespace="http://ws.*.*.*.com">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://ws.*.*.*.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.*.*.*.com">

            <xs:element name="closeSet" type="tns:closeSet"/>
            <xs:element name="closeSetResponse" type="tns:closeSetResponse"/>

            <xs:complexType name="closeSet">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="instanceId" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="activationDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Custom binding used <jxb:bindings version="2.0"  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings >
    <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                    parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                    printMethod="org.apache.cxf.tools.common.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for formatting the question. (This is my first post ;) )

Answer (score 0):

By changing the factory class from JaxWsDynamicClientFactory to DynamicClientFactory, I was able to generate the dynamic client with the datetime field mapped to java Date. Still not sure why it did not work with JaxWsDynamicClientFactory ;)